# Centering Image inside DIV for Vertical/Horizontal Images

Tags: html, css

As a curious HTML learner I want to implement following thing:-

1. I have a below div
     `<div id="divImageStyle" style ="float:left;>`
2. Now I placed an image inside the div which I am able to do successfully.

But now I want to achieve following thing:-

If image is vertical like below then it should place/start at the center of div.:-

[image]

If image is horizontal like below then it should take the whole area of div.

[image]

I hope I am able to explain my query. 
I have tried margin-left but it shift horizontal image too and "vertical-align" CSS wont work. 
Please help me with the CSS style to achieve the goal.

Comment: [`img { display: block; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 100%; }`](http://jsbin.com/jofibi/1/edit) Good luck!

Comment: The image moved some bit from left side but not coming at the middle of div even there exist lot of space on right hand side.

Comment: Better to provide an [online example](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate the issue in action.

Comment: I was missing the width of div. After putting the fix width the image comes to center. Thanks for giving extended support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that?

```
div img{
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
max-width:100%;}
```